# Build:Cannot Find type definition file for 'mocha' in tsc file after updating to angular 4

Tags: angular

I am updating my current project version to Angular 4. And I am getting error like `Build:Cannot Find type definition file for 'mocha' in tsc file`

I updated project using below steps.

1. npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
2. updated stypescript version to 2.3.1

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "build:aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~4.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.20.12",
    "typescript": "^2.3.1",
    "typings": "^1.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "rollup": "^0.41.4",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.0-dev.20170207",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are seeing there is that Visual Studio is trying to build your typescript for you on compile, but doesn't know about your separate build process from your npm scripts.  I think you can safely just disable this feature if you have another compile process like in this article:  http://rostacik.net/2015/08/14/how-to-disable-building-of-typescript-files-in-visual-studio-2015/

The important steps being:
add node

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

to the first

```
<PropertyGroup>
```

element in .csproj file.